# Exporting GAM function output in R

Tags: gam, mgcv

I am using the mgcv package in R studio to create a model with the gam function. I have made the neccessary plots but I would like to export the result of the model in excel to work with the data. Do you know how I can export the result of gam in tables/excel?

Thank you

Comment: What do you consider the “result” to be? There is no way to export the `gam` object as it is not a table or easily translated to Excel. If you mean something else, like fitted or predicted values, then pleases clarify your question and we can show you what you need to do.

Comment: I used the add_fitted function from the gratia package and it worked after all. I just wanted to print the results of gam to excel. Sorry for the wrong clarification but thank you for your reply.